# How to auto adjust the column in excel in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating an excel file  with apache poi the excel is generated  but i  can not adjust the column with  according to the cell values  i am posting the code what i have done so  far

This is how i have created the  headers in excel

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        sheet.protectSheet("password");
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(15);
        HSSFFont hSSFFont = wb.createFont();
        hSSFFont.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        hSSFFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 8);

        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        /* cell style for locking */
        CellStyle lockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        lockedCellStyle.setLocked(true);

        HSSFRow row = null;

        HSSFCell cell = null;

        row = sheet.createRow(0);
        int headercolumnNo = 0;



        //1st Column Header for Indicator
        cell = row.createCell(headercolumnNo);
        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listOfActiveCarrierUserHeader.get(0)));
        style.setWrapText(true);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFont(hSSFFont);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        headercolumnNo = 1;

        cell = row.createCell(headercolumnNo);  //2nd Column Header for Firstname
        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listOfActiveCarrierUserHeader.get(1)));
        style.setWrapText(true);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFont(hSSFFont);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        headercolumnNo = headercolumnNo + 1;

        cell = row.createCell(headercolumnNo);  //2nd Column Header for Firstname
        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listOfActiveCarrierUserHeader.get(2)));
        style.setWrapText(true);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFont(hSSFFont);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        headercolumnNo = headercolumnNo + 1;

and this is how i have  populated the values in that excel file 

for(CarrierActiveUser carrierActiveUser : listOfCarrierUser){

            int columnNo = 0;
            row = sheet.createRow(j + 1);

            cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
            if(null != carrierActiveUser.getFistName()){

                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(carrierActiveUser.getFistName()));
                 lockedCellStyle.setFont(hSSFFont);
                 cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);

            }else{
                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);
            }

            columnNo = columnNo + 1;
            cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
            if(null != carrierActiveUser.getLastName()){

                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(carrierActiveUser.getLastName()));
                   lockedCellStyle.setFont(hSSFFont);
                cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);

            }else{
                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);
            }

            columnNo = columnNo + 1;
            cell = row.createCell(columnNo);
            if(null != carrierActiveUser.getLastName()){

                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(carrierActiveUser.getEmailId()));
                lockedCellStyle.setFont(hSSFFont);
                cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);

            }else{
                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(" "));
                cell.setCellStyle(lockedCellStyle);
            }
```

Please someone help me to  adjust the columns , i am new to apache poi

[image: Current output]

Comment: How you want to adjust? Which column? Clarify.

Comment: @Ravikumar i want to  adjust  the  column according to the header , for example  if the  firstname is 10 character the header will be adjuste as well

Comment: Not clear enough, edit your question and add something like _current output is this_ and _the expected output should be like this_.

Comment: @Ravikumar see i  have attached a screen what is  output is coming and i want to adjust the  header length  with the  cell  values

Comment: Do you want the header names to come in single line? Or Do you want the columns to be aligned perfectly without overlapping on other columns?

Comment: @Ravikumar column to  be aligned  perfectly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` method to align the columns perfectly.

This method adjusts the column width to fit the contents, read the [doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29).

After setting all cell values for all columns you can use this method, in your current code call this method after for loop.

Sample code

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
```

Note - You have to do this separately for all columns which you want to be aligned and the call to `sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` should be made after populating the data into the excel. Calling before populating data will not have any effect.

Comment: Be aware that autoSizeColumn is slow, especially on sheets with merged regions.

Comment: Hi I know I'm late but when i use sheet.autoSizeColumn(0); it seems to work correctly but still be slightly smaller than needed. If i autofit the column width's in excel itself it ticks up a few pixels, has anyone else experienced this or does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @BrendanRobert Not sure but may be font issue. Check out these links [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943493/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-resizes-incorrectly) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573993/setting-column-width-in-apache-poi/11574647).

Comment: giving Error:   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.<clinit>(SheetUtil.java:111)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:235)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(HSSFSheet.java:2165)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(HSSFSheet.java:2147)