# Apache POI - Keep original picture scale while fitting within a merged region

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to fit a picture into the center of a merged cell region. The merged cell region is always only one column wide, but multiple rows high.

If the picture does not fit inside the cell region, it needs to resize, while keeping the original proportions.

```
    int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, pictype);
    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
    anchor.setCol1(column);
    anchor.setRow1(row);
    anchor.setRow2(row+rowspan);
    anchor.setCol2(column+1);
    Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    pict.resize();

    short rowHeight = (short)0;
    for (int i = row; i<row+rowspan; i++ ) {
        rowHeight += sheet.getRow(i).getHeight();
    }
    int rowHeightPx = heightUnits2Pixel(rowHeight); // (from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837639/1320704][1] )
    int columnWidthPx = (int) (sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(column));
    int pictWidthPx = pict.getImageDimension().width;
    int pictHeightPx = pict.getImageDimension().height;
    float scale = 1;
    if (pictHeightPx > rowHeightPx) {
        float tmpscale = (float)rowHeightPx / (float)pictHeightPx;
        if (tmpscale < scale) scale = tmpscale;
    }
    if (pictWidthPx > columnWidthPx) {
        float tmpscale = (float)columnWidthPx / (float)pictWidthPx;
        if (tmpscale < scale) scale = tmpscale;
    }
    anchor.setDx1(
        (int) ((sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(column)- pict.getImageDimension().width) /2)
    );
    pict.resize(scale, scale);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see I did not get the desired effect. This picture is a square (256x256) but somehow it got distorted even though scale is passed the same for x and y. Also the height does not match. And it is not centered.

For comparison, here is the same picture in the original size:

[image]

And here is what I actually want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that if you wants using `Picture.resize`, then create an anchor with upper left cell `Col1` and `Row1` only. Only a one cell anchor since bottom right anchor position depends on resizing.

Second problem is that you should do the resizing only after upper left anchor position is well known inclusive `Dx1` and `Dy1`.

But main problem is that your `heightUnits2Pixel` does not get the correct pixel heights of the rows. There is [Row.getHeightInPoints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getHeightInPoints--) which should better be used. This gets the row height in `pt` but this can be converted to `px` using `rowHeightPt * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI`. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html.

Using that at least the scale factor gets calculated correct because it now has the correct row heights in pixel.

To set the `Dx1` of the anchor being the horizontal center position there is an additional problem. The meanings of `Dx` and `Dy` are very different between `XSSF` and `HSSF`.

In `XSSF` it is the horizontal center position in unit `EMU`. So you need calculating `horCenterPosPx * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL` for `Dx`. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html.

In `HSSF` the values of `Dx` are dependent on the factor of `column-width / default column-width` and the values of `Dy` are dependent on the factor of `row-height / default row-height`. See [apache poi XSSFClientAnchor not positioning picture with respect to dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117).

For calculating the vertical center position at first the correct `Row1` of the anchor neeeds to be determined. Even if merged, there are different rows present. So `Row1` of the anchor needs to be the correct row where the picture shall start. The remaining pixels up to the vertical center position are the `Dy1` then.

Following complete example works for me. It puts any kind of images of different size scaled and centered into the merged range `A3:A12`.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CenterImageTest {

 static void putPictureCentered(Sheet sheet, String picturePath, int pictureType, int column, int startRow, int rowspan) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = sheet.getWorkbook();

  //load the picture
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(picturePath);
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
  int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, pictureType);
  inputStream.close();

  //create an anchor with upper left cell column/startRow, only one cell anchor since bottom right depends on resizing
  CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setCol1(column);
  anchor.setRow1(startRow);

  //create a picture anchored to Col1 and Row1
  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

  //get the picture width in px
  int pictWidthPx = pict.getImageDimension().width;
  //get the picture height in px
  int pictHeightPx = pict.getImageDimension().height;

  //get column width of column in px
  float columnWidthPx = sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(column);

  //get the heights of all merged rows in px
  float[] rowHeightsPx = new float[startRow+rowspan];
  float rowsHeightPx = 0f;
  for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+rowspan; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
   float rowHeightPt = row.getHeightInPoints();
   rowHeightsPx[r-startRow] = rowHeightPt * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI;
   rowsHeightPx += rowHeightsPx[r-startRow];
  }

  //calculate scale
  float scale = 1;
  if (pictHeightPx > rowsHeightPx) {
   float tmpscale = rowsHeightPx / (float)pictHeightPx;
   if (tmpscale < scale) scale = tmpscale;
  }
  if (pictWidthPx > columnWidthPx) {
   float tmpscale = columnWidthPx / (float)pictWidthPx;
   if (tmpscale < scale) scale = tmpscale;
  }

  //calculate the horizontal center position
  int horCenterPosPx = Math.round(columnWidthPx/2f - pictWidthPx*scale/2f);
  //set the horizontal center position as Dx1 of anchor
  if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   anchor.setDx1(horCenterPosPx * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); //in unit EMU for XSSF
  } else if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
   int DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH = 10 * 256;
   anchor.setDx1(Math.round(horCenterPosPx * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 14.75f * DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH / columnWidthPx));
  }

  //calculate the vertical center position
  int vertCenterPosPx = Math.round(rowsHeightPx/2f - pictHeightPx*scale/2f);
  //get Row1
  Integer row1 = null;
  rowsHeightPx = 0f;
  for (int r = 0; r < rowHeightsPx.length; r++) {
   float rowHeightPx = rowHeightsPx[r];
   if (rowsHeightPx + rowHeightPx > vertCenterPosPx) {
    row1 = r + startRow;
    break;
   }
   rowsHeightPx += rowHeightPx;
  }
  //set the vertical center position as Row1 plus Dy1 of anchor
  if (row1 != null) {
   anchor.setRow1(row1);
   if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    anchor.setDy1(Math.round(vertCenterPosPx - rowsHeightPx) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); //in unit EMU for XSSF
   } else if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
    float DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 12.75f;
    anchor.setDy1(Math.round((vertCenterPosPx - rowsHeightPx) * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 14.75f * DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT / rowHeightsPx[row1]));
   }
  }

  //resize the picture to it's native size
  pict.resize();
  //if it must scaled down, then scale
  if (scale < 1) {
   pict.resize(scale);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); String resultName = "CenterImageTest.xls";
  //Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); String resultName = "CenterImageTest.xlsx";
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  int column = 2;
  int columnWidth = 100; //in default character widths
  int startRow = 2;
  int rowspan = 10;

  //========================prepare sheet
  //create cell A1 and set cell value
  Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(column);
  cell.setCellValue("Picture of product");

  //create the cells with different heights
  for (int r = startRow; r < startRow+rowspan; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   row.setHeightInPoints(12 + r*2);
  }
  //merge cells
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(startRow,startRow+rowspan-1,column,column));
  //========================end prepare sheet

  //set column width of column in default character widths
  sheet.setColumnWidth(column, columnWidth * 256);
  //put image centered
  //String picturePath = "./logo.png"; // small image
  //putPictureCentered(sheet, picturePath, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, column, startRow, rowspan);
  String picturePath = "./Bilder/Sample-jpg-image-1.jpg"; // bigger image
  putPictureCentered(sheet, picturePath, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, column, startRow, rowspan);

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(resultName);
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  wb.close();

 }
}
```

---

There seems to be a bug in [Picture.resize](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize-double-) if the picture is small and `Dx1`is set for the anchor. The scale factor `scale` gets correctly calculated from this code but `pict.resize(scale)` does not scale height and width proportionally. It scales the height using the correct factor. But it scales the width not using the same factor but a much bigger factor.

I have filed bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64213.

---

To avoid the buggy `Picture.resize` we could calculating the full two cells anchor. We have `Col1` and already are calculating `Dx1` and `Row1` and `Dy1` to have the top left point of the picture. Now we could additional calculating `Dx2` and `Row2`and `Dy2` to have the bottom right point of the picture too.

Example im my `putPictureCentered` from above:

```
...
/*
  //resize the picture to it's native size
  pict.resize();
  //if it must scaled down, then scale
  if (scale < 1) {
   pict.resize(scale);
  }
*/

  //set Col2 of anchor the same as Col1 as all is in one column
  anchor.setCol2(column);

  //calculate the horizontal end position of picture
  int horCenterEndPosPx = Math.round(horCenterPosPx + pictWidthPx*scale);
  //set set the horizontal end position as Dx2 of anchor
  if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   anchor.setDx2(horCenterEndPosPx * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); //in unit EMU for XSSF
  } else if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
   int DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH = 10 * 256;
   anchor.setDx2(Math.round(horCenterEndPosPx * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 14.75f * DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH / columnWidthPx));
  }  

  //calculate the vertical end position of picture
  int vertCenterEndPosPx = Math.round(vertCenterPosPx + pictHeightPx*scale);
  //get Row2
  Integer row2 = null;
  rowsHeightPx = 0f;
  for (int r = 0; r < rowHeightsPx.length; r++) {
   float rowHeightPx = rowHeightsPx[r];
   if (rowsHeightPx + rowHeightPx > vertCenterEndPosPx) {
    row2 = r + startRow;
    break;
   }
   rowsHeightPx += rowHeightPx;
  }

  //set the vertical end position as Row2 plus Dy2 of anchor
  if (row2 != null) {
   anchor.setRow2(row2);
   if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    anchor.setDy2(Math.round(vertCenterEndPosPx - rowsHeightPx) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL); //in unit EMU for XSSF
   } else if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
    float DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 12.75f;
    anchor.setDy2(Math.round((vertCenterEndPosPx - rowsHeightPx) * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 14.75f * DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT / rowHeightsPx[row1]));
   }
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. For me this example works only if the picture is smaller than the provided space. [picture](https://imgur.com/e8aG3cY) If I change rowspan to 4 the picture gets distorted again and positioned to the right of the cells [picture](https://imgur.com/AsC3YOj)

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs: Cannot reproducing. For me it works for `XSSF` as well as for `HSSF`. I am using `apache poi 4.1.2`. What apache poi version are you using? Can you upload your image file somewhere, so I can test it using that picture?

Comment: I am using 4.1.2 as well. The only changes I made to your code was change picture type to png, change rowspan to 4 and cellrangeaddres to 2,5,0,0. Here is the [picture](https://easyupload.io/ufis59) I also tried with a jpg picture and got the same result.

Comment: The picture I uploaded breaks with rowspan <= 8. Here is the generated xlsx file when I set rowspan to 8: [CenterImageTest.xlsx](https://easyupload.io/ybz50p)

Comment: I tested with some new pictures and it worked with every picture except the one I uploaded. So I guess the picture is the problem somehow.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs: there seems to be a bug in [Picture.scale](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize-double-) if the picture is small. The scale factor `scale` gets correctly calculated from this code but `pict.resize(scale)` does not scale height and width proportionally. It scales the height using the correct factor. But it scales the width not using the same factor but a much bigger factor.

Comment: I resized the picture to 450x450 and then it works fine, but there seems to be some additional issues. I came across [this picture](https://imgur.com/BGxb0Yd) which is a JPG picture 773x780. It also gets distorted. What I did then was open the picture in Pinta, saved it under a different name without changing anything, and the [new picture](https://imgur.com/9voICDP) works just fine. Maybe the original picture is missing some metadata or information that POI uses?

Comment: I downloaded ImageMagick and did `identify -verbose` on the two pictures. The bad picture has `Resolution: 300x300` in the metadata and that may be messing up POI. Here is the diff between the metadata for the two pictures: [diff output](https://pastebin.com/JtT3hSG1)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but do you know how I can fix this when adjacent rows are multiline (have wrapped text inside them)? [The pictures end up stretched.](https://ibb.co/92xyBY7)

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs: The whole approach only can work when row heights are set explicitly. If there is text wrap in cells, that is not the case. Then row height is calculated dynamically by `Excel`'s `GUI` while rendering. So no chance here since `apache poi` only has the stored settings in the `Excel` files.